# Validity of proof $\zeta(s) \neq 0$ for $\sigma\gt1$, where $\sigma$ is the real part of $s$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, euler-product

The Riemann zeta function is can be expressed as an infinite series, as well as an infinite Euler product over primes $p$.

$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_n 1/n^s = \prod_p(1-1/p^s)^{-1} $$

Here $s=\sigma+it$ and the function is defined for $\sigma>1$.

A natural question to ask is whether there are any zeros in the region $\sigma>1$.

**Question:** Is the following outline proof sufficient and correct?

---

**Step 1**

We note that none of the factors $(1-1/p^s)^{-1}$ is ever zero, because $p^s = e^{s\ln(p)} \neq 0$ for $\sigma>1$.

---

**Step 2**

The previous step is insufficient. We also need to demonstrate that the infinite product doesn't converge to zero.

To do this, we make use of the following convergence criteria:

- if $\sum|a_n|$ converges, then $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges to a finite non-zero value.

---

**Step 3**

In this case $\sum |a_n| = \sum 1/p^s$, which we know converges for $\sigma > 1$.

Therefore the Euler Product converges to a non-zero finite value.

Comment: @Tariq I'll delete the comments under this post. Please join our chatroom before that: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128089/tariq-and-vitamind

Answer (score 1):

Your step 2 is overlooking some subtlety (for instance, what if $a_{17} = 1$ but the series still decays fast enough to converge?). To get around subtleties, proceed as follows.

1. If $\prod |1-a_n|$ converges, then so does $\prod (1-a_n).$
2. Hence, instead of looking at a product of possibly complex numbers as in the factorization of $\zeta(s),$ look at their magnitudes, each of which we know is nonzero.
3. Prove that if $b_n$ are strictly positive reals, then $\prod b_n$ converges to a non-zero real if and only if $\sum \log b_n$ converges, which is fairly immediate by taking logarithms of partial products/exponentials of partial sums (to do this directly with the complex numbers requires more effort since the logarithm requires a branch cut to be defined, so we just take absolute values to reduce to positive reals and avoid that).
4. Now conclude as in your step 2 above. (It's helpful to use the limit comparison test to change the log series into a series not involving logs, getting closer to your original formulation of step 2.)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. I am still trying to understand it, and have two immediate questions. (Q1) What are the subtleties? In your example, $a_{17}=1$ can't happen because $1/p^s \neq 0$ for finite $s$. (Q2) your suggestion to consider $\prod b_n = \prod |(1-1/p^s)|$ means we have to work with $\sum \log |(1 - 1/p^s)|$ which doesn't seem easy.

Comment: @Tariq As stated, the lemma in your step 2 is incorrect. That's what I was pointing out. And like I said, use the comparison test, noting that $\log |1-p^{-s}|$ looks like $|p^{-s}|.$

Comment: hi @Michael-barz, the lemma is stated in several sources incl here as Theorem 6: http://www.ma.man.ac.uk/~mdc/MATH41022/Background/Background%20Inf%20Prod.pdf and also theorem 6.5 here http://people.math.binghamton.edu/dikran/478/Ch6.pdf ... I feel I have a fundemental misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @Tariq you forgot to specify $a_n \neq 1$ for all $n$, which is included in the first pdf you cited. Without that hypothesis you can't guarantee that the value the product converges to is non-zero. That's what Michael was pointing out.

Comment: Hi @silvascientist thanks for your help. Do you mean $a_n\neq-1$ as per the first pdf? If so, $\sum |a_n|=\sum |-1|=\sum 1$ diverges, so the criterion doesn't hold anyway? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tariq You just have to ensure that none of the $a_n$ terms are equal to one. If any one of them equals one, then (1 - a_n) becomes zero and the product vanishes. This isn't an issue of divergence, but rather ensure that the limit to which it converges is a *nonzero* value

Comment: @silvascientist - ok understood. Doesn't step 1 exclude the possibility of such zero=valued factors? If yes, then what is the error in step 2?